# What's the lyrics to Onra's "Like the Seasons"?

Tags: lyrics

Onra's "Like the Seasons" on [网易](http://music.163.com/#/song?id=477839399) has a few guesses to it's lyrics:

> 风，在外面淫……

> 你……在外面你……

I thought it sounds like 不在外面营, I did think it sounded like 淫 at first but I don't think it's a song for sex ed.

Any ideas?

[Genius](https://genius.com/Onra-like-the-seasons-lyrics) says it's just an:

> [Instrumental]

but there are obviously samples with *speech* on it.

[YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtzYqBs4bLE) comments:

> 有人听出采样在唱什么吗？求采样﻿

*anyone know what the sample is singing?*

> Anybody have a translation?﻿

Comment: Could that be... "风，在外面吟 (moan/ recite)"? both 吟 and 淫 is pronounced  yín

Comment: It really sounds like ..."oooh, 在懷念你".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perhaps [Shanghainese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanghainese) [Mandarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandarin_Chinese). This song tries to create an old atmosphere from the early 20th century in Shanghai. Onra probably intentionally make it very blurred and unclear. But back then, people who do not live in Beijing their Mandarin accent is not accurately. They would mix their hometown local accent with the standard Mandarin accent.

After listening this song couple times. As a Shanghainese, it sounds like "我...在怀念你" (I'm missing you) to me.Some comments under [网易云](https://music.163.com/#/song?id=477839399) also mentioned this. In the song, "我" sounds like "吾", which is close to its Shanghainese pronunciation; and "怀念" also sounds close to Shanghainese. So it's a Shanghainese lady speaking Mandarin. However, I cannot give you a 100% sure answer.

Answer (score 0):

I searched on Onra, who is apparently a Frenchman. This song is collected into his 3rd Chinoiseries album. I found no lyrics for this track.
My best guess is that the album is just mimicking Chinese, not real Chinese (Mandarin) nor any dialects.
The "lyrics" on comments are just Soramimi (homophone).

Comment: It's more likely a *random* sample than anything else. If you listen to the track it, clearly, sounds like standard Mandarin.

Answer (score -1):

Is just a joke, a sense of humor in which our chinese people use homophone to mislead the meaning.

But the true meaning is tough to guess,because it maybe the 上海 local accent.

侬，怀念你 maybe